# Select with only condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query to see if a record does not belong to the item group. But I do not want to select the record if the record has only the item group.

```
 Select * from dt_prj where item_group not in ('apple', 'mangoes') and prj ='abc'
```

This gives me all the records which don't have apple/mangoes. But what I need is if the record has 'apple','pear' for project 'abc' it has to be selected but if the project 'abc' has only 'apple' it shouldn't be selected. How can I do that.

Comment: could u provide some sample data and your expected output

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation if you just want the items that match:

```
select item
from dt_prj
where item_group not in ('apple', 'mangoes') and
      prj ='abc'
group by item
having count(*) = 2;  -- use count(distinct item_group) if dupiclates are allowed
```